# Android-Java Facebook API Error validating access token

Tags: java, android, api, facebook

I'm creating an social application in which I have Sign-up from Facebook. Everything work fine. But recently from user Facebook profile URL  I'm not getting its profile picture.
First this URL  `"https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large"` work fine, but after few days getting profile picture like this:

[image]

After that I looked on internet and Found we need to add **Access Token**. Now the new **URL** is this `String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large&access_token=" + getString(R.string.access_token);` After that getting the **exception** from that URL.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 467,
      "fbtrace_id": "Apk45eAb6DZG9oQGBd6vTmw"
   }
}
```

**Note**: If still question is unclear, I would be glad if you add your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Solution**:
You can just pass your *app ID* and *app secret* as the `access_token` parameter when you make a call:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/{api-endpoint}&access_token={your-app_id}|{your-app_secret}"
```

**Source**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens